# Upload file using Ajax call using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to upload a file in my page using:

```
<input type="file" name="FileName">
```

I have a button, clicking on which an ajax post is done.

```
$.ajax({
           cache: false,
           async: true,
           type: "POST",
           url: '@Url.Content("~/OCR/OCRProcessor")',
           data: '',
           success: function (data) {
               $('#ocrresult').val(data);
           }
       });
```

I would like to get the file uploaded in the controller action method something like below:

```
HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files["FileName"] as HttpPostedFileBase
```

Please let me know the **optimal way** to achieve this task.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jquery [Forms plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) ([GitHub Link](https://github.com/malsup/form/))would be an ideal choice in this context.
You can simply do it like this. (Include the file input in this form)

```
$('#myFormId').submit(function() { 
    // submit the form 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(); 
    // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
    return false; 
});
```

[Demo](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/progress.html)

This would be a No plugin approach (only in Html5), but I'm still recommending the plugin

```
$("#myFormId").submit(function(){

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "YourPath/ToAction",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;
});
```

Another nice [plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API).

Comment: Can you suggest any way to do this without using jquery Plugin.

Comment: I would like to know if it can be achieved just by using the .ajax()

Comment: using html5 formdata object you can do it. This jQuery plugin is also doing the same. But it has its own fall back mechanism if Html5 is not supported

Comment: i will try that. But please let me know if any other ways are there to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Code show here

```
        if (window.FormData !== undefined) {

                var fileUpload = $("#FileUpload1").get(0);
                var files = fileUpload.files;


                var fileData = new FormData();
                fileData.append('Type', Type );  //other requered pass data
                fileData.append('name', dataRow.CustomerName);  //other requered pass data
                fileData.append('Id', dataRow.InvoiceId);  //other requered pass data
                fileData.append('subject', Sub);  //other requered pass data
                fileData.append('message', Mess);  //other requered pass data

                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Email/SendEmail',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: fileData,                     
                    success: function (data) {

            if (data == "No") {
                alert("Email Not Exist in Customer Master." );
            }
            if (data == "Not") {
                alert("Email Not Exist in System Setting.");
            }
            if (data == "NotExist") {
                alert("File Not Exist or Some Other Error");
            }
            if (data == "PassNot") {
                alert("Email Password Not Exist in System Setting.");
            } 
            if (data == "NotFile") {
                $('btn-Print').trigger('click');
            }
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err.statusText);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("FormData is not supported.");
            }
```